# Swiper with Meteor

Tags: meteor, scroll, swiper.js

I need swipe horizontally with dynamic data in meteor, but it still not simply working, any idea?
My code:

```
<template name='gallery'>
  <div class="swiper-container" id="swiper-container1">
     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        {{#each gallery_images}}
          <div style="background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,{{base64encoded}})"></div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is the helper function and swiper registration

```
Template.gallery.helpers({
      gallery_images: function(){
        return Images.find();
      }
    });
Meteor.startup(function(){

    console.log('Initial Swiper');
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        resistance : '100%',
        createPagination:false,
        loop: false
    });
    swiper.reInit();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Meteor.startup(function(){...
```

Use;

```
Template.gallery.onRendered(function(){ ....
```

The DOM is not populated with all the div's at startup, that only happens after the template has been rendered with the data from `{{#gallery_images}}` and not until then can you `new` the Swiper class